# Sending Image from C# to Android via JSON

Tags: c#, android, sql-server, json, image

I have images stored in SQL server, and I want to send them to Android app via JSON with other data. What's the best way to do this?
BTW my server side written in ASP Web API(C#).

In other way I want to make my image like this http://myserver/image.jpg
so I can included in my JSON and download it in Android app.

Comment: `server side written in C#` Does that mean you have an `API` or `webService`

Comment: Your question is unclear, [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help a lot. If you go to Stack overflow and ask "hey, how do i create this thing?" your question would most likely get downvotes.

Comment: my server side is ASP Web API

Comment: @khalidAlJahury Please go throw the links I'd added in the answer

Comment: and don't worry about the vote down, you'll get use to ;)

Comment: I have updated my question to be more clear

Comment: you can convert in Base64 String and pass that string in Json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figure it out 
This is the code

```
   public HttpResponseMessage getImage(String name)
    {
        name = name + ".png";
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        String filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/images/"+name);
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
        Image image = Image.FromStream(fileStream);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(memoryStream.ToArray());
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
        fileStream.Dispose();
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As its not where clear from your question, This Link is the best what I can find for you. In it he is accessing `ASP.NET WebAPI` and converting all the things to `JSON` when access or pass it through the `Andriod` studio

http://hintdesk.com/how-to-call-asp-net-web-api-service-from-android/

and here is a complete series that can help you more

http://www.tutecentral.com/restful-api-for-android-part-1/

Hope this helps

Comment: the links you provided very usefull but  I already done everything , I only want to know how to send image.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by the updated question of yours? do you have access to the `method` in `API`that gets the image?